# when should i use parallel foreach and when should i use parallel linq?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried these below code,it working fine and the performance also good.But when i run the nunit testcases its not working.I dont have idea about parallel linq or parallel foreach.Is it possible convert the code to parallel linq.Please
give your valuable suggestion.

```
Parallel.ForEach(ListofData, item =>
            {
                if (this.DataSource != null && item != null)
                {
                    string itemText = this.GetListViewItemValue(item, this.displayMember);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text) && itemText.ToLower().Equals(this.Text.ToString().ToLower()))
                    {
                        this.textBox.Text = itemText.ToString();
                        this.textBox.SelectAll();
                        this.listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: `But when i run the nunit testcases its not working.` In what way is it not working?

Comment: If I have 10 testcases, 5 test cases passed other test cases not running further

Comment: That is not sufficient detail @Sam10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CONGRATULATIONS, you were my 1000th answer**

> when should i use parallel foreach and when should i use parallel
>   linq?

They both do exactly the same thing, they are both built on the *Task Parallel Library*, and only differ in semantics.

Take a look at all the overloads and extension methods, and you will see sometimes its just easier to write *PLinq*, sometimes its easier to write `Parallel.For/Foreach`

As to your problem, its nothing to do with either approach directly. However you **ARE** trying to update the *UI* from a potentially different thread and bound to fail.

The only reason why this **wouldn't fail** is that the internals has deemed this not Thread-Worthy and is running this on the original context.

I think you really need to rethink your approach, and if you do want to use multiple threads, you will need to *Marshal* back to the *UI Thread* accordingly

> But when i run the nunit testcases its not working

As for your test cases... I think you have bigger problems at the moment, your code is not thread safe

Comment: If i upload 50000 data to the listview,it loops 50000 times so to improve the performance i used parallel foreach..... can i get any other way to improve the performance...If any please suggest....

Comment: That is a different question @Sam10.